# jssor slider, how to set duration for each slide on autoplay?

Tags: javascript, jssor

Does anyone know if you can set a duration interval for EACH SPECIFIC slide (Not transition) using **jssor** with `$AutoPlay` option set to **TRUE**?

I can now set all slide duration with `$Idle=1000ms` but I need to have for example:

```
SLIDE1: pause here for 2000ms
SLIDE2: pause here for 3000ms
...
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have just added this feature, please download the latest version.

Now you can set `$Idle` option,

and also, you can set idle time for each individual slide as follows,

```
<div u="slides" ...>
    <div><img data-u="image" src="image_url_1" /></div>
    <div data-idle="2000"><img data-u="image" src="image_url_2" /></div>
    <div data-idle="3000"><img data-u="image" src="image_url_3" /></div>
</div>
```

**Edit**
The new option should be `$Idle` instead of `$AutoPlayInterval`.
See http://www.jssor.com/development/reference-options.html

Comment: Wow Thanks!! awesome! And congratulations for your work!

Comment: What if you a specific transition for each slide?